# Next-auth working in local development environment but not working when deployed with vercel Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, deployment, oauth-2.0, vercel, next-auth

Here is my authConfig

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { prisma } from "@/prisma/db"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import { User } from "@/types/types"

export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        name: { label: "Name", type: "text" },
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      // manages the user sign up and sign in via credentials method
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { name, email, password } = credentials as User
        if (req.body?.callbackUrl.includes("login")) {
          const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: { email },
          })
          if (
            user &&
            (await bcrypt.compare(password as string, user.password))
          ) {
            return user
          } else {
            throw new Error("404")
          }
        } else {
          return await prisma.user
            .create({
              data: {
                name,
                email,
                password: await bcrypt.hash(password as string, 10),
                loginType: "credentials",
              },
            })
            .catch(() => {
              throw new Error("404")
            })
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
    signOut: "/",
    error: "/api/auth/error",
  },
  callbacks: {
    // handles sign up of google users
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      const dbUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: { email: user.email as string },
      })
      if (!dbUser) {
        await prisma.user
          .create({
            data: {
              name: user.name as string,
              email: user.email as string,
              password: "null" as string,
              loginType: account?.provider as string,
            },
          })
          .catch(() => false)
        return true
      }
      return true
    },
    // returns the role property from the token to the current user session
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.role = token.role
      }
      return session
    },
    // generates a token for the current user
    async jwt({ token }) {
      const dbUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: token.email as string,
        },
      })
      if (dbUser) {
        return {
          name: dbUser.name,
          email: dbUser.email,
          role: dbUser.role,
        }
      }
      return token
    },
  },
}
```

This is the log when trying to sign in with google or credentials in vercel app.
[sign in logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1pIS.png)

I don't understand why this doesn't work, my environment variables have been setup correctly as I can access the login page.

Also, when I attempt to sign in with google It says the serverless function timed out when trying to redirect me to the home page after signing up.